# How to make customers to stop placing order after shop closing time in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, stores, time

Am designing one restaurant website and their delivery time 10:00 Am to 10:00 Pm. How to make customers to placing order after the working hours. Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sales_order_place_before` event to stop placing order after a specific time.

In your config (this is part of config.xml)

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before> 
                <observers>
                    <stop_placing_order>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>stopOrder</method>
                    </stop_placing_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In your observer you can have this function:

```
public function stopOrder($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $postCode = $address->getPostcode();
    $currentTime = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    // make your timing conditions... i just give the example of if() condition.

    if($currentTime <= 10:00:00 am || $currentTime >= 10:00:00 pm )
    {
       Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('Store has been closed');

       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
       Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
       exit;
    }
}
```

**I haven't tested but this should do the trick for you.**